# My excel macro does not automatically recognize all numbers that are equal

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare two different datasets, and have written an Excel macro to do so, for code see below. My problem is that when I paste numbers from the external data, and my macro compares it with the data in my warehouse, for some cells it does not recognize that they are equal and I get the message "Deviance". However if I click into these cells, and don't edit them just click into them and press enter the macro recognizes that they are equal, and returns "OK".

Macro code:

```
Function compare(relevant, source 1, Source 2, n)

 deviance = False

 For i = 1 To n
     If relevant(1, i) <> "" Then
    If broker(1, i) <> nhc(1, i) Then deviance = True
End If
 Next i

If deviance Then
   compare = "Deviance"
   Else
   compare = "OK"
End If
```

In Excel the system looks like below.

[image]

Comment: Try it like this and see if that works: If Val(broker(1, i)) <> Val(nhc(1, i)) Then deviance = True

Comment: ^^ and, better still, change the statement to be performed when the values aren't the same from `deviance = True` to `deviance = True : Exit For` - there is no point looking at all the rest of the values once you decide that one of them is not equal.

Comment: floating calculation problems?

Comment: Hopefully going to learn something here - in the function arguments how can you have a space: `source 1` and `source 2`?  Are they even used?

Comment: I edited away the names of these two, there should not be spaces as you point out.   Unfortunately I cant use Val, this is because I also need to control the currency.  And in repect of the break line, I use this sheet to get an overview of which lines differs, but otherwise I see the thought behind the solution ;).

Comment: I think I might have figured out why I get a deviation, and why it gets solved when I click it.

If I take the value where I get deviation, lets call it A, and subtract the number from my warehouse, lets call that B. The value should be #DIV/0!,  however  (A-B)/(A-B) = 1. Meaning that there is a difference between the two numbers, and that when I click A the format or something changes.